# XNA Float values don't work as parameter

Tags: xna, c#, color, floating-point

With the Microsoft XNA Framework I can change the color of a tinted texture by changing it's integer values like so:

```
Int x = 255;
if(true) { x--; tint = new Color(x, 255, 255); }
Draw(texture, Vector2.Zero, tint);
```

If x were a float however the appearance of the sprite wouldn't change until the value x became zero. With integer the texture fades over time with the event change.

Why is this? :S

Comment: because color constructor either takes 3 floats ,or 3 bytes. It doesn't work for both.

Comment: The reason is that the constructor which takes floats assumes that the floats are within [0, 1] range. So basically instead of giving floats a value between [0, 255], give them a value between [0, 1].

Answer (score 4):

It's because of how overload resolution works in C#. Of the available [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.color.aspx) with three arguments, there are:

```
Color(int, int, int)
Color(float, float, float)
```

If you pass all integers, you get the integer version. But if you pass a `float` for any of the parameters, you get the `float` version (and the integers will be implicitly converted to `float`s).

The integer version takes values in the range of `0` to `255`. The `float` version takes values in the range of `0.0f` to `1.0f` for each channel (and converts them internally to cover the integer range).

(See also [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/31/color-constructors-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx))